# C using void function to compute sums of files

Tags: c

I have an assignment that requires the use of a function
`void stats(FILE *in, int *count, double *sum);` , which is supposed to compute the sum, average, and integer count of each file. We are supposed to call the function by using `stats(in, &count, &sum)` . I'm confused as to how exactly I'm supposed to send the results back to main if the stats function has a void return type. Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Through the pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Your function signature indicates that each parameter is a pointer argument (they begin with a *). Declare (and possibly initialize) those variables in your main function, then pass the addresses of those variables as indicated in the way you're told to call the function: `stats(in, &count, &sum)`. The function will modify those variables in main scope using the pointers you passed to it, without returning any value. This is an example of [pass (or call) by reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).

So overall, your main function will have something like:

```c
int main(void)
{
    /* some FILE opening here */
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    stats(in, &count, &sum);

    /* rest of your main function */
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to understand more about what the * and & mean, you should go through how pointers work in C – [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) is a very basic resource to get you started.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk -- "*for portability return `EXIT_SUCCESS`*": this is incorrect. Further, "_remove `return` at the end_" would be fine (for C99 or later), but in this case a value of 0 is returned from `main()` anyway. But it doesn't matter, because: ["_If the value of `status` is zero or `EXIT_SUCCESS`, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned._"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.4p5) `EXIT_FAILURE` is more useful; in any case, it would be good to point out that `stdlib.h` is required for both of these macros.